LLM/OpenAI/ChatGPT Fails to Follow Character Length Requirement
I have a project where I need to generate text with a specific character length, but the model(using "langchain" gem) is sometimes generating responses that are either too short or too long.
Sample prompt I used: (top_keyword = "Basketball")
**Task Objective:** Generate unique titles in different locales where each title starts with the #{top_keyword} in the respective locale's language, and ensure the titles are distinct across all locales. The titles must strictly follow length and structure constraints while ensuring uniqueness across all locales.

**Main Keyword in Locale Language:** The title must start with the main keyword (top_keyword) in the respective locale's language. 
**Character Length:** In each locale, the title must be strictly between 25 and 30 characters, including spaces.
**Uniqueness Across Locales:** Ensure that each title is unique across all locales. Titles in different locales must not repeat or be similar to one another, even if they contain the same main keyword.
**Locale-Specific Titles:**  Generate distinct meaningful titles for the following locales:
    en-US
    ar-SA
    es-MX
    ko (Korean)
    pt-BR (Brazilian Portuguese)
    ru (Russian)
    vi (Vietnamese)
    zh-Hans (Simplified Chinese)

**Output Format:** Return an array of title objects with the locale, the corresponding title and the character count of the title:
[
    { "locale": "en-US", "title": "en-US Title", character_count: <character count of title> },
    { "locale": "ar-SA", "title": "ar-SA Title", character_count: <character count of title> },
    ...
]

    PROMPT

Sample output:
    Here are the unique titles starting with "Basketball" for each specified locale, strictly between 25 and 30 characters long:
        
            [
  {
    "locale": "en-US",
    "title": "Basketball Highlights Pro",
    "character_count": 28
  },
  {
    "locale": "ar-SA",
    "title": "كرة السلة: أفضل المباريات",
    "character_count": 29
  },
  {
    "locale": "es-MX",
    "title": "Baloncesto Estrella Total",
    "character_count": 29
  },
  {
    "locale": "ko",
    "title": "농구 매니아 하이라이트",
    "character_count": 27
  },
  {
    "locale": "pt-BR",
    "title": "Basquete Heróis do Jogo",
    "character_count": 28
  },
  {
    "locale": "ru",
    "title": "Баскетбол: Лучшие моменты",
    "character_count": 29
  },
  {
    "locale": "vi",
    "title": "Bóng Rổ: Siêu Sao Đỉnh",
    "character_count": 27
  },
  {
    "locale": "zh-Hans",
    "title": "篮球精华赛精彩集锦",
    "character_count": 28
  }
]

    
    Each title meets the character length requirement while being unique and localized.

I have tried both the default gpt-3.5-turbo and gpt-4 models.
when reviewing the response, I noticed that the character count does not align with the response. The AI confirms that the titles should be between 25-30 characters, yet when checking the zh-Hans title, it shows only 10 characters but is listed as 28. Similarly, the ko title is reported as 27 characters, which is also incorrect.
How can I enforce a strict character length on the output of OpenAI's models?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You have conflicting requirements -- translating a 25-30 character title will not always result in a 25-30 character result.

Updated my prompt

What happens if such a "title" does not exist? Also I'd like to point out that "must not repeat or be similar to one another" is a) subjective; and b) fails miserably across your outputs. It appears the issue may be your use of the word "translate" as the results appear to be attempted translations of the same or similar concept, which obviously cannot be guaranteed within a specific character length. For instance it appears that "Basketball Best Plays of 2024" and "Баскетбол – красивая игра" would both work for your intensions but the LLM is trying to keep with theme of "best of 2024".

I requested meaningful titles. There's no issue if a title does not exist. I have updated my prompt accordingly. However, when reviewing the response, I noticed that the character count does not align with the response. The AI confirms that the titles are between 25-30 characters, yet when checking the zh-Hans title, it shows only 9 characters but is listed as 28. Similarly, the ko title is reported as 27 characters, which is also incorrect.

@Beu unfortunately at this point I believe this question is no longer about programming and boils down to the fact that the LLM generates inaccurate results for your given prompt, this is an issue with the LLM itself and cannot be solved by SO users. Just for fun I used your prompt corrected ChatGPT4 a couple of times until I obtained the desired result then asked the best possible way to phrase this question to obtain the desired results. I used the exact wording suggested and in turn it generated incorrect results....

...I then asked it to verify each result no less than 5 times and if any result failed it needed to generate a new one and start the verification process over. It has been processing that requirement for 30 minutes now. Long story short LLM's have limitations and regardless of how specific you are, you may not always get your desired result.
